# How Do I Use Multiple Internet Connections at the Same Time

Tags: sharing

I want to write a program to make all my internets work at the same time. and combine them together. so that IDM can use all internets. please help

Comment: This question does not appear to be about programming or software development, so it is not a good fit for Stack Overflow.

Comment: A web search tells me that "IDM" probably stands for "Internet Download Manager".  The answer as to how to use multiple network connections at once is almost certainly OS specific (the answer on a Mac will be different than on Windows than on Linux), so it would be impossible to answer even if it were on topic for Stack Overflow.